# Change notepad++ default search options

Tags: notepad++

When searching in Notepad++, often the check boxes "Match case" and "Match whole word only" are ticked without me having ticked them; I think it happens first time I search after starting Notepad++. Usually I want to search without those options ticked, though... and often I forget to check and wonder why it's not finding anything.

Is there a way to untick these options by default? I checked the Settings->Preferences as well as the config files but didn't any way to do so yet...

Answer (score 1):

Seems I didn't check the config files thoroughly enough; there is an option for that there.

In config.xml there is an element "FindHistory" with matchWord and matchCase attributes; when changing them to "no" the checkboxes are disabled!

So:

```
<FindHistory [...] matchWord="no" matchCase="no" wrap="yes" [...]>
```

Comment: Well done. For me, it seems like it saves whatever setting I used in the previous search. So if you had them checked, they will (still) be checked next time you open the search dialog.

Comment: that works for me as well, as long as Notepad++ is open. As soon as I close and reopen it, it reuses the settings from the config.xml; that could be permission-related though